# How to add JLabel in a JPanel Vertically?

Tags: java, swing

I'd like to add JLabels dynamically in a JPanel vertically like the image that I've attached. After loading all images, I need to select an image, then selected the image should appear in another JPanel. I am reading Images from an ArrayList which contains the paths.

I used Jpanel with GridLayout in a JScrollPane, but the result is not the same that I want.

This is the code that I've used to add Jlabels:

```
for(String file: files) {                   
                    JLabel JLabelPicture = new JLabel(new ImageIcon(file));
                    panel_images.add(JLabelPicture);
                }
```

[image]

Comment: “the result is not the same that I want” Can you explain what result you saw instead?  And please add the code that creates the GridLayout and JPanel to your question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I used Jpanel with GridLayout in a JScrollPane, but the result is not the same that I want.

A `GridLayout` will allow you to display the components vertically. When you create your panel you just use:

```
JPanel imagePanel = new JPanel( new GridLayout(0, 1) );
```

This will resize all the images to the same size.

Another option is to use a vertical `BoxLayout`. In this case you can use:

```
Box imagePanel = Box.createVerticalBox();
```

In this case the images will retain their preferred size.

In both case you add to the panel to a scroll pane which is added to your frame:

```
frame.add( new JScrollPane( imagePanel ) );
```

Read the Swing tutorial on [Layout Managers](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/visual.html) for more information and working examples of each layout.

Edit:

> after listing the images I need to select one of them,

Well where was that requirement in your original question. The complete requirement should be defined in the question so all the information is in one place for everybody to see.

So I would suggest you should be using a JList to display an Icon. Read the section from the Swing tutorial on [How to Use Lists](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/list.html) for more information.

Comment: Thanks for replying me, I used your codes, but these images should have ability to select. I mean after listing the images I need to select one of them, then the selected image should appears in another panel. this code just generates 1 row with all images. Please let me know, using Jpanel is good idea? or I should use other tools?